# Как изменить обращение на другой адрес в ida pro?

Tags: linux, ассемблер, hex, x86-64, ida-pro

ASM

```
......
.text:000000000062D153   lea   rax, aaa ; "aaaaaaaaaaa"
.text:000000000062D15A   lea   rdx, bbb ; "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
......
.rodata:0000000000F63221 aaa     db 'aaaaaaaaaaa',0                                               
.rodata:0000000000F6322D bbb     db 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',0 
.rodata:0000000000F6323E align 20h
......
```

HEX

```
......
000000000062D153  48 8D 05 C7 60 93 00
000000000062D15A  48 8D 15 CC 60 93 00
......
```

Я не могу понять, где зашит адрес `aaa`(`F63221`) в hex `48 8D 05 C7 60 93 00` ?
Как заменить `a` на `b` в hex, чтобы получилось ?

```
 .text:000000000062D15A                 lea     rdx, aaa ; "aaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Comment: Платформа x64 ведь?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, да x64 Linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае используются не непосредственные адреса, а относительные, причем относительно конца команды.

Пример: берем адрес aaa (0xF63221), вычитаем адрес команды, следующей за `lea   rax, aaa` (0x62D15A), получается 0x9360c7. Записываем в виде байт (в обратном порядке): `C7 60 93 00`. Смотрим на код команды, и видим именно эти 4 байта в конце.

> Как заменить a на b в hex, чтобы получилось `lea     rdx, aaa` ?

Это замена `bbb` на `aaa` во второй команде (а не `a` на `b`).

Считаем относительный адрес: `0xF63221 - (0x62D15A + 7) = 0x9360c0` ; (7 - длина команды)

Записываем в виде байт: `C0 60 93 00`

Заменяем эти 4 байта в коде команды, получаем: `48 8D 15 C0 60 93 00`

Для проверки берем следующий код, компилируем с помощью flat assembler:

```
use64
org 62D153h
lea   rax, [aaaa]
lea   rdx, [aaaa]

org 0F63221h
aaaa     db 'aaaaaaaaaaa',0
bbbb     db 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb',0
```

Смотрим полученный код в шестнадцатеричном виде (разбито по командам):

```
48 8D 05 C7 60 93 00 ; lea   rax, [aaaa]
48 8D 15 C0 60 93 00 ; lea   rdx, [aaaa]
...
```

Шестнадцатеричный код второй команды выглядит именно так, как и ожидалось.